# Keep a column in place when scroll horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to solve a problem scrolling a page horizontally. In simplified scenario I have one row and two columns. When I scroll I want to keep left column as fixed. Here is my
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhbh0w0q/)

and code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="border-style:solid;background-color: #fff;">123456</div>
  <div class="col-xs-10" style="border-style:solid">abcde</div>
</div>
```

When you make the running area small enough you get a horizontal bar. scrolling to the right will move both columns but I need to prevent left from moving. I tried using fixed position for it but then the second column ovelaps first one. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: something like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/bqfspr0n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more solution:

```js
$(".innerdiv").height($(".row").height());
```

```css
.wrapperdiv {
    overflow-x: auto;
    background-color: #9c9;
}
.innerdiv {
    width: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #575; background-color: #6a6;">
    <div class="col-xs-2 left">123456 asd asdasq sdasd asd asd asd asdas fsdf sdfsfsdfsdf sdfsdfs</div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 wrapperdiv"><div class="innerdiv">abc fds sdf<br> sadf de</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is close. Will I be able to use a body scroll to scroll second column's content?

Comment: How it could exceed viewport limits if you use bootstrap grid?

Comment: I guess when I resize the Browser. Ideally, I am trying to achieve the following: When I resize the Browser I get both scroll bars that are body scroll bars. When I scroll, the content in the left column which is a navigation bar is not moving, but the content in the second column gets scrolled by these body scroll bars. Sorry, if my question was misleading.

Comment: I'd rather play with grid tuning for small and extra-small viewports. I would define cells: letf: `<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 left">` and right: <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12 wrapperdiv">, thus on -xs- viewport  both divs will be full width and  "left" stacked  over "right"

Comment: My problem with that is if I have scrolling working around the second column I am getting a nice vertical scroll bar that moves to the left with the browser window when I make a page smaller horizontally, but  I am not getting a horizontal bar unless I scroll all a way down vertically. Resizing the page vertically will hide the scroll bar. That's why I am trying to work with body scroll bars. The only thing I cannot make working is to protect my navigation bar in the first column from moving.

Comment: so try to use z-index for fixed position: `.left {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}`

Comment: If I use fixed for .left then the second column is positioned right under the first one.

Comment: I think it's another question. You primary asked to make content of right section scrollable horizontally. If you want to fix left column and make right column to not go under left, so just make different `<div>` fixed on the left, then make a row with offset by 2 div: `<div class"col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be helpful?

https://jsfiddle.net/fhbh0w0q/2/

```
<div class="col-xs-10" style="border-style:solid; width: 450px;">abcde</div>
```

Believe issue was that you were using % as a width, that's why it all collapsed.

Hope this helps,

A.

Comment: No, not really. The second solution from Banzay is much closer to what I need, but thanks anyway.